# A bug happens in the Footer and the code keeps appearing

Tags: debug, footer, bug

On this WordPress site with the Newspaper theme, the footer appears and looks normal (as you can see in https://www.vendaonline.pt/), but I installed a question plugin (DW Question Answer) and on the pages corresponding to the content of each subject, keep the footer with bug (https://www.vendaonline.pt/foruns/teste1/).
The problem happens only on pages dedicated to the individual subject only. Can anyone help me solve the problem?
[image]
[image]

Comment: What you're seeing isn't an error code, it's the shortcodes for WPBakery's Visual Composer monstrosity.  What appears to be happening is that on pages where there's content from your DW QA plugin, it somehow breaks the WPB's VC code that follows.  You've either got a bug in the DW QA plugin or the way that plugin is implemented in your theme, or there is an outright conflict between WPB VC and the DW QA plugin.  My suggestion is that you reach out to the three parties (Newspaper theme devs, WP Bakery devs and DW Question Answer devs) for support.

Comment: If you like, also include the code that shows how you're implementing/including the content from the DW QA plugin - maybe there's something there someone can see.